# why can I not use an alternating series test to find out if the sequence below converges or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{i=1}^∞ \frac{(-1)^i(i^3+1)}{i^3+7}$$ why can I not use the alternating series test on this series to determine convergence?

Comment: Well...do the terms go to $0$?

Comment: I know that it diverges, but doesn't this sequence meet the definition of an alternating series. So why can't I use the alternating series test to find convergence?

Comment: Can you state the Alternating Series Test?  It's not like it says "all alternating series converge" or anything like that.  Some conditions need to be met.

Comment: it says a sequence only converges if each term in the series gets smaller than before, and the series goes to 0 over time. But why can't I use this to show the series diverges?

Comment: Have you tried finding the first five terms of the series?  Are their absolute values decreasing to $0$?

Comment: The question in my textbook states can we use the alternating series test to determine if this series converges or diverges. And the answer to the question is you cannot use the alternating series test to determine converges or divergence. So I'm wondering why that answer is correct, not if the sequence diverges or converges

Comment: The alternating series test, in its usual form,  only goes one way.  If the (absolute value of the) terms decrease to $0$ then it converges.  That's it.  Of course, if the terms don't go to $0$, it diverges.  That's even more basic.  But there are convergent alternating series where the terms do not strictly decrease.

Comment: So, what you're saying is as n gets larger if the terms of the alternating series don't decrease for all n or n greater than or equal to some natural number x, then we can't use the alternating series test even if the series is an alternating series right.

Comment: Yes,  that's right.  The test simply doesn't apply.  Again, this isn't really relevant here since your terms don't even go to 0.